# Simple jquery slideshow breaks when adding <li>

Tags: jquery

There are a lot of solutions similar to what I'm trying to do but when I try tweeking to suit what I need they always break

I've a simple

```
<ul class="slideshow"><li>IMAGE</li><li>IMAGE</li></ul>
```

structure - it needs to be this way so the client can easily change it through CMS

the solution at http://jsfiddle.net/KA4Zq/ works well but when I add < l i > it breaks - I'm presuming because of the child?

http://jsfiddle.net/KA4Zq/347/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `:nth-child` selector, you need to target only the children of the `ul` element so you need to use the children selector instead of descendant selector

```
var count = 1;
setInterval(function() {
    count = ($(".slideshow > :nth-child("+count+")").fadeOut().next().length == 0) ? 1 : count+1;
    $(".slideshow > :nth-child("+count+")").fadeIn();
}, 2000);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sLB8V/), [also this](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/sLB8V)

Comment: i think downvoter thought how can someone be so quick so he downvoted in hurry without checking.

Comment: Cool - haven't got a clue what that means or how it works but it does and adds to the learning experience so thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Add "li:nth-of-type" instead of " :nth-child".

Complete JS:

```
    var count = 1;
setInterval(function() {
    count = ($(".slideshow li:nth-of-type("+count+")").fadeOut().next().length == 0) ? 1 : count+1;
    $(".slideshow :nth-child("+count+")").fadeIn();
}, 2000);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KA4Zq/348/)

Also a positioning for the "li":

```
.slideshow > li {
   position: relative;
   top: -20px;
   left: -10px;
}
```